# Replace the values of a data.frame using a given cluster table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe named 'databasis' in R having the following data

[image]

I am trying to create a new data.frame by assigning each percentage value of table 'databasis' a letter from the below cluster table.

[image]

For example, for company Aa in 200202 the letter assigned to the percentage would be equal to C.

[image]

Code for table 'databasis'

```
company <- c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd") 
sector <- c("B", "A", "E", "Z") 
lastmarketcap <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 
X200202 <- c(0.0833, 0.0002, 0.00, 0.0085) 
X200203 <- c(0.2308, 0.00, 0.0083, 0.0042) 
X200204 <- c(0.125, 0.0007, 0.00, 0.0084) 


databasis <- data.frame(company, sector, lastmarketcap, X200202, X200203, X200204)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: please don't post images of your code or data

Comment: it's not an image

Comment: Have a look at the `cut()` function

Comment: You have 3 images of data in this post. I'm not trying to be mean. I'm trying to help you by telling you what will be the most helpful for you as you ask questions here going forward.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will be more careful next time :) @DanHall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we create a breaks vector corresponding to the max column in your image, labels corresponding to the grade column, and then cut each column into a factor with those labels.

```
breaks = c(-Inf,-0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 100)
labels = rev(LETTERS[1:6])
f <- function(col) cut(col, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
new <- data.frame(databasis[1:3], lapply(databasis[-c(1:3)], f))
new
#   company sector lastmarketcap X200202 X200203 X200204
# 1      Aa      B            18       C       A       B
# 2      Bb      A          4571       D       E       D
# 3      Cc      E           122       E       D       E
# 4      Dd      Z           239       D       D       D
```